# Escalating to Ring 0 in Linux application

Tags: security, linux-kernel

I want to use `monitor` and `mwait` instructions in a userspace application. Unfortunately, they're privileged instructions only executable by ring 0.

My application has root access. How can I escalate privileges to ring 0?

I've considered a kernel module that adds them as a syscall, but that destroys the performance improvement I need them for.

Compiling a custom kernel is an option. I have no idea where in the source the switch to ring 0 might be located however, nor if it'll have any side-effects on e.g. virtual memory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get a ring0 from user-space with standard linux kernel. And it's preferable to write a kernel module to do thinks you want. But if you really want to have a ring0 at user-space, I'll give you a start point.

x86 processors stores *Current Privilege Level* in the two least significant bits of `cs` register.

When new thread is created, Linux kernel checks whether this thread is user thread or kernel one and stores appropriate `cs` value for this task. (Proof: `copy_thread()` in `arch/x86/kernel/process_32.c`).

So, you are able to get pointer to task registers with `task_pt_regs()` (`arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h`) macro and alter `cs` to set ring to `0` with `regs->cs &= ~0x3;` or something similar.

But again, I strongly recommend you, don't do it.